# MapKit in Airplane Mode

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have 30 `MKPinAnnotations` on a map in my area. I also have a series of arrays of 30 more locations relative to each of those 30. The experience I want is to be able to tap one of those pins, and the other 30 relative pins show up around it. When I do everything with full internet connectivity, this is the result:

[image]

I am using Realm to cache everything on the backend, so I know I have the data available to me. Tapping the blue pin brings up a callout view that allows me to "check in" to this location, which should summon the 30 other relative locations. This is the code that drops my pins for me:

```
if let annotations = currentRestaurantAnnotations {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
}
currentRestaurantAnnotations = nil
currentRestaurants = nil
var restaurantPins = [RestaurantAnnotation]()
for restaurant in restaurants.filter({ $0.venueID == currentFocusVenue?.id }) {
    let pin = RestaurantAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: restaurant.latitude, longitude: restaurant.longitude), title: restaurant.name)
    restaurantPins.append(pin)
}
currentRestaurantAnnotations = restaurantPins
mapView.showAnnotations(restaurantPins, animated: true)
```

Again, debugging on this when I have connectivity, all of the annotations make it to the last line. When I put the device in airplane mode, and I tap the blue pin and its callout button, this method gets triggered again, and everything runs in the code as it should, but after `showAnnotations()` runs, the map view shows no annotations.

For context, if I then take the device out of airplane mode, the app does what it should by triggering an update from the cloud of those 30 relative locations. This function to show the annotations is triggered again, and the annotations all show because my device is in airplane mode.

Tl;dr: how do I make annotations show up on MapKit when my device is in airplane mode?

Comment: are you using a high accuracy for gps that depend on internet/wifi ? that could be one of the reasons...... try to change accuracy to low.

Comment: Your asking this question like it's a map issue but it sounds like it's a realm issue. You may want to rephrase your question to be more Realm specific.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen ok I'll try that!

Comment: @CleverError sorry but that's not the case - the data comes from Realm well formed in airplane mode, and when I make my collection of `MKPinAnnotation`s, those are formed the same too. When I try to `showAnnotations`, the pins do not show up. I am very confident this is not a Realm issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `addAnnotations` with `setVisibleMapRect` instead of `showAnnotations`?

Comment: @LukeVanIn just tried that - same exact type of result.

Comment: Well, I was able to solve the problem, but I am still not sure whether the issue is Realm or MapKit. Incase it is Realm, mea culpa to @CleverError :-] I put each variable from the Realm object into raw vars, and then construct the `MKPinAnnotation` object from those raw vars. However, I then have to set a `Timer` to wait 0.1 seconds before adding the annotations to MapKit. If I don't set this `Timer`, then MapKit will still behave as before. One of these two on their own doesn't fix it, but both put together do. I wonder if Realm has a memory copy issue. In any case - problem solved for now!